# How to create a dynamic size array

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

**What I am trying to achieve:**

I have a UITableView and I want to check whether the table was selected or not and keep in an array easy to access the YES or NO values that corresponds to that row so that afterwards i can manipulate the data.

my code as follows

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *cellLabelText = cell.textLabel.text;

    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        selected[row] = NO;
    }
    else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        selected[row] = YES;
    }  
}
```

As it stands out I can create a `BOOL selected[some value]` but my problem is that the max index needed for me is unknown as my table size changes constantly. thus setting the max index limits me.

I am new to objective C and I come from a PHP background thus I dont know whether it is possible to create an array that does  what i want to do in objective-c.

Otherwise what would be my options within objective-c to have an easy way to easy write/read  `selected[row] = YES/NO`.

I need a way to write YES/NO  and link it to the indexpath.row

Comment: Have you considered just getting the selected index path when you need it?

Comment: @MarcusAdams This is for selecting multiple rows, not just one row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an `NSMutableSet` and store the `NSIndexPath` of the selected rows. If you select a row you add the path to the set. If you unselect a row, remove the path from the set.

To see if a row is selected, see if the indexPath is in the set or not.

BTW - this only works if the rows are fixed. If the user can add, remove, or reorder rows then this approach will not work. In such a case you need to store data keys, not index paths.

Create an ivar of type `NSMutableSet`. Let's call it `selectedRows`:

```
selectedRows = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
```

Then in `didSelectRow` you do:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    BOOL selected = [selectedRows containsObject:indexPath];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *cellLabelText = cell.textLabel.text;

    if (selected) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        [selectedRows removeObject:indexPath];
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        [selectedRows addObject:indexPath];
    }  
}
```

In your `cellForRow...` method you do something similar:

```
BOOL selected = [selectedRows containsObject:indexPath];
cell.accessoryType = selected ? UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
```

Comment: Thank you! could you provide me a little example please? I never used sets

Comment: I just tried to add a NSLog(@"%@",selectedRows); at the end of that function to see what it throws and it always throw null

Comment: Did you initialize `selectedRows` in your `init...` method or `viewDidLoad`? I showed the code (just before the `didSelectRow...` method.)

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
NSMutableArray *dynamicArray = [NSMutableArray array];
```

You can add and delete objects from this at will. Just be sure to use the `NSNumber` wrapper to add primitives:

```
[dynamicArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexNumber]];
// or
[dynamicArray addObject:@(indexNumber)];
```

Comment: I still need the BOOL there and guessing that if i use an NSMutableArray i wont be able to have both assiciated to each other, i am better off with a dictionary.

Comment: You can also add BOOLs like this `addObject:@YES`

Comment: but then I would have dynamicArray{indexNumber,BOOL,indexNumber,BOOL,} and it wouldnt be associated. dynamicArray{indexNumber => BOOL}

Comment: Just a tip when using `NSMutableArray` you can give it a size hint by using `+ arrayWithCapacity:` which really just gives a performance boost because it starts the mutable array off with enough space for `n` objects.

Comment: The array is *ordered*, remember. So setting `objectAtIndex:indexNumber` to YES/NO would work.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of an array you can use a index set.

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableIndexSet *pickedIndexPaths;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    _pickedSIndexPaths = [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc] init];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //…

    if(indexPath.section == 0) {
        cell.textLabel.text = self.sports[indexPath.row][@"sport"][@"name"];
        if ([_pickedIndexPaths containsIndex:indexPath.row]) {
            [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
        } else {
            [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
        }
    }
    return cell;
}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([_pickedIndexPaths containsIndex:indexPath.row]) {
        [_pickedIndexPaths removeIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        [_pickedIndexPaths addIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    [tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

Comment: feel free to add an array of index sets, one for every section.

Answer (score 0):

When what you need is a variable length array of boolean values, you can use `CFBitVectorRef`.  This will consume much less memory than using a Cocoa collection designed for objc object values (provided of course that array has many elements) because it consumes 1 bit for each value, rather than a full pointer which points to an individual dynamically allocated reference counted object.